# Find a value in column in hive

Tags: hive

I have a requirement in hive to find a value in a column, data is ";" separated values in single column. if my required value present it should result TRUE else FALSE.

Ex: data in a single column is

Row1: insurance;finance;telecom

Row2: insurance, retail

Row3: finance, telecom, internal

Like this I have different values in a column.
I wanted to find if the column contains "finance" or not. If present it should result TRUE else FALSE

output:
Row1: TRUE

Row2: FALSE

Row3: TRUE

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for single hardcode value, you can use like operator.
`where col like '%finance%'.`

But if you want it to be a variable qnd coming from another table you can use it like this

```
Select...
From table1 t1,
join table2 t2 on t1.col like concat('%', t2.colpattern, '%')
```

Comment: Where and like conditions filter the records, but I don't want the records to be filtered.

Comment: Add a case when to replace where. E.g. `select case when col like '%finance%' then true end as output from mytable`